# Unable to send data to server from React client

Tags: javascript, reactjs, postman

I have a spring boot backend with a react front. I'm trying to register users and save them into the database but it doesnot seem to work. I've tested the spring boot api with postman and it works. SO it must be a problem with react but I don't understand what. Other post functions are working fine.

Register.js:

```
class Register extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      username: "",
      fullName: "",
      password: "",
      confirmedPassword: "",
      errors: {}
    };
    this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
    this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  onSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const newUser = {
      username: this.state.username,
      fullName: this.state.fullName,
      password: this.state.password,
      confirmedPassword: this.state.confirmedPassword
    };

    this.props.createNewUser(newUser, this.props.history);
  }

  onChange(e) {
    this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      Html form 
    );
  }
}

Register.propTypes = {
  createNewUser: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  errors: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  errors: state.errors
});
export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  { createNewUser }
)(Register);
```

Action.js:

```
 export const createNewUser = (newUser,history) => async dispatch => {
        console.log("test");
        console.log(newUser);
        try{
            await axios.post(`http://localhost:8080/api/user/register`,newUser);
            history.push("/login");
            dispatch(
                {
                    type:"GET_ERRORS",
                    paload:{}
                }
            );
        }catch(err){
            dispatch({
                type:"GET_ERRORS",
                payload:err.response.data
            });
        }
    }
```

Error: there seems to be an error in a js file from kaspersky. I've tried disabling the antivirus but still doesn't work.
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/15E36.png)

Comment: Photo of error doesn't seem helpful. Could you post it as a text. What does it say besides code 400?

Comment: I've updated the photo. Error seems to be from a js file from kaspersky with 2000+ lines of code. I've disabled the antivirus and even removed the extension but still doesn't work